# Выбор папки Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

У меня есть `shiny` приложение, в которое я хочу добавить возможность выбора папки. Данное приложение используется в локальной сети.

Пробовал :

```
#UI
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
                            actionButton("goButton","Choose folder"),
                            textOutput("session"))

) 
#server 
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    if(input$goButton > 0){
      output$session <- renderText(function(){
        list.files(choose.dir())})
    }


  })

})
```

При запуске с моего ПК все работает хорошо, но когда другие пользователи пытаются выбрать папку, окно для выбора появляется на моем ПК , а не на их.

Есть ли способ реализовать выбор папки со стороны других пользователей?

[Оригинальный вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357127/choose-dir-shiny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте пакет [`shinyFiles`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyFiles/index.html). Для примера смотрите:

```
shinyFilesExample()
```

Решение без использования сторонних пакетов:

```
dirs <- list.dirs(path = "some/path")
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    selectInput("dir", "Choose dir", choices = dirs, selected = "."),
    verbatimTextOutput("dir")
))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$dir <- renderPrint(input$dir)
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Можно отфильтровать переменную `dirs` перед тем как использовать её в `selectInput` или привести её в более читаемый вид..

Comment: На локальной машине всё вроде бы сносно. Если пакет вас не устраивает, то можно попробовать нагородить `list.files` + `selectInput`.

Comment: Пакет очень медленно работает когда пытаюсь открывать папки в локальной сети, в итоге видимо нагорожу с динамическими `selectInput` Спасибо!